# distinct count with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have already searched SO but found no answer to my question. My question is if I use the query below I get correct count which is 90:

```
select count(distinct account_id) 
from FactCustomerAccount f
join DimDate d on f.date_id = d.datekey

-- 90
```

But when I group by CalendarYear as below I am missing 12 counts. The query and output is below:

```
select CalendarYear,count(distinct account_id) as accountCount
from FactCustomerAccount f
join DimDate d on f.date_id = d.datekey
group by CalendarYear

output:

CalendarYear    accountCount
2005    10
2006    26
2007    49
2008    63
2009    65
2010    78
```

I am not sure why I am missing 12 counts. To debug I run following query if I have missing date_id in FactCustomerAccount but found no missing keys:

```
select distinct f.date_id from FactCustomerAccount f
where f.date_id not in  
(select DateKey from dimdate d)
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.
Can anyone please suggest what could be the reason for missing 12 counts?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT ONE:

I did not quite understand reason/answer given to my question in the 2 replies so I would like to add 2 queries below using AdventureWorksDW2008R2 where no count is missing:

```
select count (distinct EmployeeKey) 
from FactSalesQuota f
join dimdate d on f.DateKey = d.DateKey

-- out: 17

select d.CalendarYear, count (distinct EmployeeKey)  as Employecount
from FactSalesQuota f
join dimdate d on f.DateKey = d.DateKey
group by d.CalendarYear

-- out:

-- CalendarYear Employecount
-- 2005         10
-- 2006         14 
-- 2007         17
-- 2008         17
```

So please correct me what I am missing.

Comment: This is only a case. In that DB distinct EmployeeKey in 2008 are 17, and is the same number of all distinct employeekey.

Comment: Shama: Show the integration on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't missing 12. It could be that some accounts didn't have activities in the final years.

Answer (score 3):

Your queries are very different:

The first:

```
select count(distinct account_id) 
from FactCustomerAccount f
join DimDate d on f.date_id = d.datekey
```

Return a count of different accounts (over all years), so if you have an account_id present in two years, you have 1 (count) returned.

The second:

Grouped by CalendarYear so if you have an account_id in two different years, this information goes in two different rows.

```
select CalendarYear,count(distinct account_id) as accountCount
from FactCustomerAccount f
join DimDate d on f.date_id = d.datekey
group by CalendarYear
```

**EDIT**

I try to explain better:

I suppose this data set of order couple: (year, account_id)

```
`2008 10`
`2009 10`
`2010 10`
`2010 12`
```

If you run two upper queries you have:

```
`2`
```

and

```
`2008 1`
`2009 1`
`2010 2`
```

because exist two different account_id (10 and 12) and only in the last year (2010) account_ids 10 and 12 have written their rows.

But if you have this data set:

```
`2008 10`
`2009 10`
`2009 12`
`2010 12`
```

You'll have:

First query result: 
    `2`

Second query result:
    `2008 1`
    `2009 2`
    `2010 1`

Answer (score 1):

i will say to analyze this,check number of rows.check calender column.Is there any rows with null in calenderyear .or try rank,i am not sure

```
select *,
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by CalendarYear,account_id order by CalendarYear)
from  FactSalesQuota f
join dimdate d on f.DateKey = d.DateKey
```